# A random "Could not load cross-domain" message when loading Esri map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

My application displays an Esri map, by accessing the Esri public sampleserver. I use Esri dojo API for this purpose. The Esri dojo I use is of version 1.6 and is locally installed (as a war) on my server. It's important to say that the rest of my dojo code is an older dojo version (1.3.2).
I use Firefox 3.6 and the strange thing is, I sometimes get a "Could not load cross-domain resources" message (at about **10%** of my attempts). This problem happens more often on another pc (Firefox 3.6 as well): at about **80%** of my attempts. It is usually (but not necessarily) solved after clearing Firefox cookies and cache.
Now, I know the code is ok, as I can see the map in most of my attempts. However, I can't figure out why it sometimes fails on my browser, and why the other browser almost constantly fails.
What do you think? What could be the cause for it?

Comment: According to this [blog](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcobjectsdevelopment/archive/2009/09/28/ArcGIS-RIA-Developers_3A00_-Practical-pointers-about-cross_2D00_domain-policies-_2800_Part-2_2900_.aspx), I should be able to see the crossdomain.xml file loaded when my browser succeeds on displaying the map, but I can't see it - perhaps this implies on the problem?

Comment: have you tried testing your App with Firebug? Using the 'Net' tab, you should see all the requests and should be able to see which one is failing. That will help in narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Dvedatta, I did what you suggested and installed firebug on that browser in order to view the net tab.
Surprisingly, installing firebug solved the problem: the map started appearing at about 90% of my attempts, just like in the first pc I tried. In my opinion, the reason for the failures is the fact that the Esri server is remote, and the map load delays due to networking issues. I think that firebug delays the page load and therefore the map has enough time to load too. I think that a permanent solution would be changing the browser's timeout programmatically.